ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow is possible to get and set the camera position
ARNode webGLB object Scaling and rotate is not working in ar_futter_plugin. Also facing the FirebaseSDK cocoa Pod issue .synlink folder. Found another ar_flutter_plugin_flutterflow: ^0.7.46 FirebaseSDK cocoa Pod issue not occurred.
But ARNode object is scaling and rotate is not working when camera position is near to object. how we set the object in camera position and set width and height.
